# How to apply wordpress filter to ajax loaded data?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have created an ajax function and a filter for content, but my filter does not work when I am getting data using ajax response. Please help me. Here is my code:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_thb_infinite_ajax", "thb_infinite_ajax");
add_action("wp_ajax_thb_infinite_ajax", "thb_infinite_ajax");
function thb_infinite_ajax() {
   $args = array(
        'p' => $previous_post->ID,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

        the_content();
    endwhile; else : endif;
}

add_filter ( 'the_content', 'wpsabox_author_box', 5 );

wpsabox_author_box($content) {
    return $content.'----';
}
```

JS code:

```
$.ajax( ajaxurl, {
    method : 'POST',
    data : {
        action : 'thb_infinite_ajax',
        post_id : tempid
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        id = null;
    },
    success : function(data) {
        //container.removeClass('thb-loading');
        $( ".thb-loading" ).remove();
        $(data).appendTo( '#infinite-article' );
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add javascript code

Comment: Ajax code is not important but i am not getting WordPress filter data

Comment: Note that the filter function must return the content after it is finished processing

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...may be helpful to you  I change the_content function

```
function thb_infinite_ajax() {
   $args = array(
        'p' => $previous_post->ID,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

        $result = get_the_content($post->ID);
    endwhile; else : endif;
echo $result;
}
```

Comment: how i will add my filter to get_the_content function like this: add_filter ( 'the_content', 'wpsabox_author_box', 5 );